# MySQL Union Missing Rows of Second Query

Tags: mysql, union, union-all

I have two queries which are working separately as expected. When I have used union to get results of both queries at a time, no rows from second query is fetched. My query is simplified as follows:

```
( select 
    tmp.inv_id AS inv_id,
    tmp.name AS inv_name,
    tmp.level AS inv_level,
    'archive' AS alarm_tpye,
    log.start_time AS start_time,
    log.end_time AS end_time 
  FROM tmp_raw_inventory AS tmp
  INNER JOIN log_alarm_archive AS log ON  tmp.inv_id=log.inv_id
  WHERE 
    log.start_time between STR_TO_DATE($date1,'%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE($date2,'%Y-%m-%d')  OR
    log.end_time between STR_TO_DATE($date1,'%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE($date2,'%Y-%m-%d')
) 

UNION

( select 
    tmp.inv_id AS inv_id,
    tmp.name AS inv_name,
    tmp.level AS inv_level,
    'active' AS alarm_tpye,
    log.alarm_time AS start_time,
    STR_TO_DATE($date1,'%Y-%m-%d') AS end_time 
  FROM tmp_raw_inventory AS tmp
  INNER JOIN log_alarm AS log ON  tmp.inv_id=log.inv_id
  WHERE 
    log.alarm_time between STR_TO_DATE($date1,'%Y-%m-%d') and STR_TO_DATE($date2,'%Y-%m-%d')
)
```

$date1 and $date2 are string date parameters passed in a correct form. The results of first query is coming but results of the second query is not coming. The rows are not unique thus I have used `UNION`. After this failure I have tested with `UNION ALL` but the result didn't changed.

Your help will be appriciated.

**UPDATE:**
Result of the first part is as follows:

```
inv_id, inv_name        , inv_level, alarm_type, start_time           , end_time
234231, 'inventory name', 'high'   , 'archive' , '2013-02-10 05:38:03', '2013-02-12 09:36:26'
234231, 'inventory name', 'high'   , 'archive' , '2013-02-10 16:10:18', '2013-02-10 17:03:13'
234231, 'inventory name', 'high'   , 'archive' , '2013-02-10 20:08:12', '2013-02-10 21:17:37'
```

Result of the second part is as follows:

```
inv_id, inv_name        , inv_level, alarm_type, start_time           , end_time
234231, 'inventory name', 'high'   , 'active' , '2013-02-10 23:27:03', '2013-02-11 00:00:00'
```

Result of whole query is the same with the first part.

Comment: Are you able to provide a dump of your data to assist in debugging?  I am also seeing the last query prematurely ends with an or. Is that how you have the actual query or did the bug sneak in when u were copyint it to SO?

Comment: Please check the update. The issue of prematurely ended query was my mistake while editing the post.